# How to Convert my custom JSON data Object into Highcharts Angular Series data?

Tags: json, typescript, object, highcharts

I have some JSON Data object and its needs to convert into Highch`your text`arts Series data, I tried lot with my minimal knowledge in JS, but I can't:
Json Object:

```
{"Matrix":[{"mdate":2002-02-09,"mvalue":33.0,"mt":23,"mb":99},
{"mdate":2002-02-09,"mvalue":34.0,"mt":23,"mb":99},
{"mdate":2002-03-09,"mvalue":39.0,"mt":23,"mb":99},
{"mdate":2002-04-09,"mvalue":340.0,"mt":23,"mb":99},
{"mdate":2002-05-09,"mvalue":348.0,"mt":23,"mb":99}
]
}
```

The above data needs to be converted to be like below:
and I want to display the mdate on x axis categories and the Matrix as title.

```
series: [
    {
      name: 'm-1',
      data: [33.0,23,99],
    }, {
      name: 'm-2',
      data: [34.0,23,99],

    },

]
```

Please help me out to fix this , Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of is the JavaScript array map() function. This will allow you to transform the data.

```
highchartData = jsonData.Matrix.map((item, index) => ({
  name: `m-${index + 1}`,
  data: [item.mvalue, item.mt, item.mb]
}));
```

Sample HighChart:

```js
const jsonData = {
  "Matrix": [{
      "mdate": "2002-02-09",
      "mvalue": 33.0,
      "mt": 23,
      "mb": 99
    },
    {
      "mdate": "2002-02-09",
      "mvalue": 34.0,
      "mt": 23,
      "mb": 99
    },
    {
      "mdate": "2002-03-09",
      "mvalue": 39.0,
      "mt": 23,
      "mb": 99
    },
    {
      "mdate": "2002-04-09",
      "mvalue": 340.0,
      "mt": 23,
      "mb": 99
    },
    {
      "mdate": "2002-05-09",
      "mvalue": 348.0,
      "mt": 23,
      "mb": 99
    }
  ]
};

const highchartData = jsonData.Matrix.map((item, index) => ({
  name: `m-${index + 1}`,
  data: [item.mvalue, item.mt, item.mb]
}));

console.log(highchartData);


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: highchartData

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```